# custom_functions wordpress enqueue_script in footer instead of header

Tags: wordpress, scripting, footer

I can get this to work in the header but how can I get it in the footer. I use thesis framework on my wordpress.

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', '/wp-content/themes/thesis/custom/js/bootstrap.min.js', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap');
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```

I put true and it doesn't seem to work. I've been using this as a reference.
    wp_enqueue_script( $handle,$src ,$deps ,$ver ,$in_footer );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing `true` in the wrong place - WordPress will interpret that as the value for `$deps`.  While `$deps` is optional, you need to provide it if you want to specify a subsequent parameter.  [The codex entry for wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) tells you the default values - just pass those.

So your `wp_register_script` call should be:

```
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', '/wp-content/themes/thesis/custom/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), false, true);
```

Probably worth using [get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo#Template_Directory) to get your template directory, rather than hardcoding it too.